# Roslyn uses MemberAccessExpressionSyntax instead of QualifiedNameSyntax

Tags: roslyn, c#-9.0

In the [following code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxNGSAmIDUAfAAQCYACAMQHsKBYAKAG86TmSCBmVgFhIFkAKCsABWcAMYwSFAJRMWjWi0UkAbhAQkJAXg0BPAA5wKAMz4EAjADpzRKQG5ZSklADuASxiiAFgJkLHJeX8lUWg4VktrEAcgpWAEOAgAa3s/RwBfaIzaNKA===), I'd expect that both references to `System.Action` type to be represented as a [QualifiedNameSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.qualifiednamesyntax?view=roslyn-dotnet) but the second one is represented as a [MemberAccessExpressionSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.memberaccessexpressionsyntax?view=roslyn-dotnet).

Is that correct? If so, why can't it be a `QualifiedNameSyntax`?

```
class Foo
{
    public void M(object o)
    {
        var t = typeof(System.Action); // 1
        switch(o)
        {
            case System.Action: // 2
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you're only going to get a QualifiedNameSyntax in a Roslyn syntax tree where the *only* legal thing there is a qualified name; in those cases we're running a restricted parser that will only understand qualified names. Anything else we're running our generic expression parser which will spit out whatever expression is there, and we'll figure out what it actually is during binding. Because consider another case like:

```
SomeEnum e;
switch (e)
{
     case SomeEnum.Blue: Console.WriteLine("Blue!"); return;
}
```

In that case the SomeEnum.Blue is absolutely an access to a member. But we don't actually know what "SomeEnum" is until binding, so we just always go with MemberAccessExpression.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you why for sure, but here's one relevant thing to think about:

In legal code, I think you're right that a switch can never accept a `MemberAccessExpression`, and so a `QualifiedNameSyntax` would be sufficient to represent this.

However let's look at some illegal code, and see what happens:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public static void M(object o)
    {
        var t = typeof(Foo.M(5)); // 1
        switch(o)
        {
            case Foo.M(5): // 2
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives 4 errors for the first usage of `Foo.M(5)`:

```
error CS1026: ) expected
error CS1002: ; expected
error CS1513: } expected
error CS0426: The type name 'M' does not exist in the type 'Foo'
```

And only 1 for the second:

```
error CS0426: The type name 'M' does not exist in the type 'Foo'
```

By allowing a more flexible grammar in the second case, error messages are much better, as they can be done at the semantic level rather than a syntax level.

Since switch expressions accept any pattern as a case, it's more likely that you'll write something invalid, so good error messages are more important in that case.